# What does repository layout mean

Tags: maven, maven-3

```
<repository>
  <id>oauth-maven-repo</id>
  <name>OAuth Maven repository</name>
  <url>http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

What does repository layout mean, compared to setting snapshots / releases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<layout>` tag is there to allow you to use the `legacy` option to support the maven 1 repository layout.  You can use it to handle fetching artifacts by configuring it in the `<repository>` tag, or you can use it with the deploy plugin to [deploy to Maven 1 repos](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-in-legacy-layout.html).

Comment: that's correct - and legacy is no longer supported in maven-3 so you'll find it's not used at the moment. If a new format is devised (and some plugins do create these, such as the AppAssembler plugin's "flat" layout), it may use the argument again

Comment: I am trying to use this repo with a maven-3 pom.xml, so can I remove it?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it safely.  The default value is `default`.