# Difference between altDeploymentRepository and altReleaseDeploymentRepository

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I use [swagger](http://swagger.io/) to generate web services clients on my project. The generated code produce a library that can be use as a Maven lib. I already successfully deploy release version into my private sonatype-nexus.

I wonder what is the difference between `altDeploymentRepository` and `altReleaseDeploymentRepository`? How `mvn deploy` select which repository to use if the two parameters are set?

As the [apache-maven deploy documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository) said :

> **altDeploymentRepository**: Specifies an alternative repository to which the project artifacts should be deployed ( other than those specified in  ). 
>   Format: id::layout::url
>
> **altReleaseDeploymentRepository**: The alternative repository to use when the project has a final version.
>
> **altSnapshotDeploymentRepository**: The alternative repository to use when the project has a snapshot version.

What exactly does

> when the project has a final version.

mean?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When [`altReleaseDeploymentRepository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altReleaseDeploymentRepository) is specified, it is always used when the project has a release (or "final") version, i.e. is not a snapshot version. When [`altSnapshotDeploymentRepository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altSnapshotDeploymentRepository) is specified, it is always used when the project has a snapshot version. [`altDeploymentRepository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository) is a default alternate deployment repository when none of the above repository were specified or used.

So to put it another way, if you have a release version, then:

- `altReleaseDeploymentRepository` will be used if specified;
- otherwise `altDeploymentRepository` will be used if specified;
- otherwise the release remote repository declared in the [`<distributionManagement><repository>`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_repository) POM element will be used if specified;
- otherwise the plugin will error because it didn't find any remote repository to deploy to.

Similarly, if you have a snapshot version, then:

- `altSnapshotDeploymentRepository` will be used if specified;
- otherwise `altDeploymentRepository` will be used if specified;
- otherwise the snapshot remote repository declared in the [`<distributionManagement><snapshotRepository>`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_snapshotRepository) POM element will be used if specified;
- otherwise the release remote repository declared in the [`<distributionManagement><repository>`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_repository) POM element will be used if specified;
- otherwise the plugin will error because it didn't find any remote repository to deploy to.