# Override repository for upload in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, deployment, publish

The story behind: I submitted a bug to some public repo in GitHub, and it was fixed, but when I asked to release these changes I didn't get any response. So I'm waiting for next library version for 2 months. So I decided to fork this repo and publish to custom Bintray. The repo is https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java

The project has multiple maven modules:

```sh
$ find . -type f -name pom.xml
./httpclients/okhttp/pom.xml
./httpclients/httpclient/pom.xml
./impl/pom.xml
./swagger-templates/pom.xml
./pom.xml
./integration-tests/pom.xml
./api/pom.xml
./coverage/pom.xml
./examples/pom.xml
./examples/quickstart/pom.xml
```

I need to publish only `impl` module.

The problem is that root `pom.xml` has parent configuration:

```xml
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.okta</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-parent</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
        <relativePath>../okta-java-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-sdk-root</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

And all deploy config is specified in `okta-parent` pom.
I tried to override repository config with (in root `pom.xml`):

```xml
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>bintray-g4s8-maven</id>
      <name>mvn</name>
      <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/g4s8/mvn/okta-sdk-impl/;publish=1</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

but it didn't help.
I have server configuration in my `settings.xml` for this repo, and it's working fine for all other projects of mine:

```xml
<settings
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>bintray-g4s8-maven</id>
            <username>g4s8</username>
            <password>...</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

When I'm trying to publish it I'm getting error:

```sh
$ mvn deploy -pl impl -Ppublish -DskipTests
...
[INFO] --- nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) @ okta-sdk-impl ---
[INFO] Performing deferred deploys (gathering into "/home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/nexus-staging/deferred")...
[INFO] Installing /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/nexus-staging/deferred/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/pom.xml to /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/nexus-staging/deferred/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/nexus-staging/deferred/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/nexus-staging/deferred/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to /home/projects/github.com/g4s8/okta-sdk-java/impl/target/nexus-staging/deferred/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Deploying remotely...
[INFO] Bulk deploying locally gathered artifacts from directory: 
[INFO]  * Bulk deploying locally gathered snapshot artifacts
Downloading from sonatype-nexus-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from sonatype-nexus-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (993 B at 412 B/s)
Uploading to sonatype-nexus-snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-20191101.130725-30-javadoc.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  58.070 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-01T16:07:41+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project okta-sdk-impl: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.okta.sdk:okta-sdk-impl:jar:javadoc:1.6.0-20191101.130725-30 from/to sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/): Failed to transfer file https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/okta/sdk/okta-sdk-impl/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/okta-sdk-impl-1.6.0-20191101.130725-30-javadoc.jar with status code 401 -> [Help 1]
```

Maven is uploading artifacts to `https://oss.sonatype.org/` instead of configured URL `https://api.bintray.com/maven/g4s8/mvn/okta-sdk-impl/;publish=1`. How can I force it to use my URL instead of parent URL?

---

Update

Effective pom shows both repositories in `distributionManagement`:

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>bintray-g4s8-maven</id>
        <name>mvn</name>
        <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/g4s8/mvn/okta-sdk-impl/;publish=1</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547358/maven-deploydeploy-using-daltdeploymentrepository) similar question.

Comment: When you look at the effective pom, which distribution management do you see?

Comment: @JFMeier I added repos from `distributionManagement` to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking like you are building a SNAPSHOT version. The configured `<snapshotRepository>` is `oss.sonatype...`. You only added a configuration for building release versions.